# How to convert Japanese date to Gregorian dates format?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to convert the Chinese dates into a gregorian format. I have three formates and I need a pattern to recognize the Chinese date.

1) 平成30年度 = 平成2018年度

2) 30年3月期  = 2018年3月期

3) 令和2年    = Year 2020

You can find the respective year against every Chinese date on these link.
These link will be helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisei
https://www.jcb.co.jp/processing/share/wareki.html

I write a code for the first date and I set the find part to 平成30年 ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Heisei & ChrW(24180)  and replacement text to ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Gregorian & ChrW(24180). Then I looped through the Heisei value to convert every year into the gregorian year. SO, Heisei value 30 is equal to 2018 in gregorian.

What I need now is to just change the find and replace values for the other two dates format and a year loop to run on all the date format.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
  Options.Pagination = False
  Dim Heisei As Integer
  Dim Gregorian As Integer
  Heisei = 20
  Gregorian = 2008
  Dim C As Integer

Do Until C = 50
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Heisei & ChrW(24180)
    .Replacement.Text = ChrW(24179) & ChrW(25104) & Gregorian & 
     ChrW(24180)
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Heisei = Heisei + 1
Gregorian = Gregorian + 1
C = C + 1

Loop
MsgBox ("Year Replaced")
```

I need Three patterns and a loop to go through all year ranges for all three dates.

1) 平成30年度 = 平成2018年度

2) 30年3月期  = 2018年3月期

3) 令和2年    = Year 2020

All I need is the above output when I run the macro in a word document.

If you have a better approach then share it how can I do this. !

Comment: Very difficult to help you since I can't detect a pattern on the two sides of the equations. How does 30 become 2018, for example?

Comment: Have you check the link that I have provided above (Wikipedia link) and check the conversion table on the wiki page (Check conversion table of Japanese dates). 30 is the Heisei value in Japanese formate and 2018 is the gregorian value. Second, the code above is for this date: 平成30年度 = 平成2018年度 only.

Comment: @CindyMeister I change the question description and added more details. Do visit this link for more understanding: https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/japan/year.htm

Comment: I would recommend using regular expressions for advanced pattern matching. You should be able to find existing REGEX for Chinese dates and use that. Handling dates can get really complicated. Use existing solutions where possible.

Comment: @HackSlash could you write it for me. I am confused about how can I run a loop through the expression without effecting the prefix and postfix characters.

Comment: No. Like I said, handling dates can be really complicated. This is something that you might need to hire someone to do if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: I have created a pattern for all dates formats and replaced it by using loops.